# How to make iframe change its position when main window is horizontally scrolled

Tags: css, iframe, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I have a problem with the **iframe** element in my UI. When I resize my screen(make it smaller) and start scrolling with the horizontal scroll it doesnt scroll to the iframe but the iframe stays on the same fixed position and it is impossible to see it.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/EnmD6/)

and the HTML:

```
<div id="top-element">Some div that has greater width than the inner div</div>
<div id="iframe-wrapper">
    <iframe src="http://www.apple.com/" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `position: absolute;` instead of fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You must centered it by adding left:50% and margin-left the half of the iframes width eg:

```
div#iframe-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-150px; /* this must be the half of the iframe's width */

 }
```

you can do the same to centered vertically by adding top:50% and margin-top:(minus the half of iframes height). You dont need bottom or "div#iframe-wrapper iframe" about positioning